# How to replace union in stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure having below queries. Is there any way to replace union into one query or any other way to optimize it.

```
Select col1,col2
from logs lg
inner join EmployeeType_1 et1 on et1.empID=lg.userID
where lg.usertype=1

Union 

Select col1,col2
from logs lg
inner join EmployeeType_2 et2 on et2.empID=lg.userID
where lg.usertype=2

Union 

Select col1,col2
from logs lg
inner join EmployeeType_3 et3 on et13.empID=lg.userID
where lg.usertype not in (1,2)
```

Comment: col1 coming from logs and col2 is et1.empID | et2.empID | et3.empID based on table.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, `col1` and `col2` come from `logs`.  Here is one way:

```
Select col1,col2
from logs lg
where (lg.usertype = 1 and exists (select from EmployeeType_1 et1 where et1.empID = lg.userID) ) and
      (lg.usertype = 2 and exists (select from EmployeeType_2 et1 where et1.empID = lg.userID) ) and
      (lg.usertype not in (1, 2) and exists (select from EmployeeType_3 et1 where et1.empID = lg.userID) )
```

Comment: thanks for response.  But nested select query might increase the execution time of whole query. Is it Better than Union?

Comment: @ManishMawatwal . . . It is probably better than a `union` because it doesn't have to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT JOIN` should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    lg.col1,
    Coalesce(et1.empID, et2.empID, et3.empID) As col2
FROM
    logs As lg
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeType_1 As et1
    ON et1.empID = lg.userID And lg.usertype = 1
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeType_2 As et2
    ON et2.empID = lg.userID And lg.usertype = 2
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeType_3 As et3
    ON et3.empID = lg.userID And lg.usertype Not In (1, 2)
```

**However,** since your example is only retrieving the `empID` column from the three `EmployeeType_X` tables, and that column is always equal to the `userID` column on the `logs` table, you don't really need to join the tables:

```
SELECT
    lg.col1,
    lg.userID As col2
FROM
    logs As lg
```